# decoding vim syntastic symbols in `spacevim`

Tags: vim, syntastic, spacevim

I hate asking a question like this, but am still rather new to `vim` and the `Spacevim` variant that I am using.

I am working in python and was trying to understand the different symbols that `vim-syntastic` is presenting the the leftmost column. I have included a picture below. 
[image]
There are symbols like `_3`, `!`, `!1`, and I can't seem to find a guide to these symbols. The warning and error signs are intuitive enough, but not these different colored indicators.

I tried to do `:help syntastic` but that did not show anything. I got an indication `E149: no help for syntastic`. I also googled around but could not find a description for these symbols in the github repo for syntastic, or in the `spacevim` documentation. I also found the syntastic help documentation on the github repo, but the error signs section does not explain any default settings, etc.  Here is the link to that. https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic/blob/master/doc/syntastic.txt

I also included a picture from the documentation, but it does not show the actual default symbol meanings. I tried to use help on the various keywords in the help message, but those did not work for me either. 
[image]

Does anyone know where to find this info.

Comment: _I tried to do `:help syntastic` but that did not show anything._ - Then either your package manager is broken, or you didn't follow the correct procedure for installing syntastic.  *There are symbols like `_3`, `!`, `!1`, and I can't seem to find a guide to these symbols.* - Why do you think these symbols are produced by syntastic? You provide zero information about your configuration.

Comment: @lcd047 so I actually did provide info about my configuration. I indicated that I use `Spacevim`. I am using the default values.

Comment: Well then, perhaps ask the `Spacevim` maintainers about all that.  As far as syntastic is concerned, this is not a supported configuration. _shrug_

Comment: @lcd047 I agree this seems like a `Spacevim` setting. Unfortunately there is no `Spacevim` tag on stackexchange, and I did not have the 1500 reputation points to create a new tag. If you can create a new `Spacevim` tag and then edit this post to include that tag, perhaps that could help.

Comment: @lcd047 no prob. Perhaps someone else who reads the post can add the tag. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I think I figured it out.

Comment: Stay the hell away from distributions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

short answer: `!` for error, `_` for number of deleted lines
signs are from vim-signify and/or syntastic.

SpaceVim override syntastic config `g:syntastic_warning_symbol`/`g:syntastic_error_symbol` with `g:spacevim_error_symbol`/`g:spacevim_warning_symbol`
your local config might have overridden those configs too.

refs:

https://github.com/mhinz/vim-signify/blob/master/doc/signify.txt#L100
https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic/blob/master/doc/syntastic.txt#L411

https://github.com/SpaceVim/SpaceVim/blob/dev/doc/SpaceVim.txt#L198
https://github.com/SpaceVim/SpaceVim/blob/dev/config/plugins/syntastic.vim

Comment: Ahh this is helpful. You know, the strange thing is that `!` does not actually represent an error. There is a red `x` symbol for errors. I could figure that out because `pylint` will indicate the error and line number. But for the purple `!` or such, there are no `pylint` errors or warnings generated. That is what is so confusing. Seems like the number like `3` is related to some sort of error group number, but not sure where those group numbers are listed.

Comment: @krishnab Which basically says there is something else messing with signs.

Comment: @krishnab I guess they are `syntastic_style_error_symbol`/`syntastic_style_warning_symbol`, try `:sign list`, let's see which signs get defined.

Comment: @georgexsh hmm this is progress. Ohhhhh. Yeah, I can see the notifications are like `SignifyChangeDelete` and such. It looks like these are actually `Git` notifications about whether a line has changed or not. So these are not errors, they are probably `git` notifications.

Comment: @georgexsh looks like these are specific to the `vim-signify` plugin. So my issue seems to stem from a bunch of plugins with similar behavior and not clear on which plugin was responsible.

Comment: @krishnab that's why I don't like the idea of vim distribution, build plugin and config one by one is preferable to me.

Comment: @georgexsh haha. Yeah, I understand you. I used emacs for years and maintained my config for years before I finally discovered `Spacemacs`. With `vim` I am still rather new. I mean there is an appeal of having sensible defaults. Otherwise it would take forever to integrate all of these plugins myself--including designing unique keybindings. I probably only use like 20% of the plugins anyway. Thanks for your help here. I guess trial and error is the only way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I am maintainer of SpaceVim, and Thanks for creating the `SpaceVim` tag, I just read the Q&A, these kind of symbols are from vim-signify, in SpaceVim we use [neomake](https://github.com/neomake/neomake) as default syntax checking plugin, to change the error/warning symbols of spacevim, you need to use `g:spacevim_error_symbol` and `g:spacevim_warning_symbol`, by default they are `✖` and `➤`.

Comment: Sure, happy that it helps. Yeah, I realized that the notations were not errors but instead change markings for git. It is a challenge when multiple plugins operate over the same space in vim--in this case the gutter. But it is understandably hard to get around that problem when you have a package that bundles many reasonable default plugins.

Comment: yeah, but to provide IDE-like feature, we need these plugins, now what I can do is improve the documentation of SpaceVim, and we wll pay more attention to this community.

Comment: yep I agree with you. Sorry if I was not clear. Sure any improvements to the documentation would be good. I tend to think that little video tutorials are always the best. Thanks for Spacevim though, and keep up the excellent work.

Comment: I will create video tutorials if I have time, :)